Community user access to cases
I have a scenario that a case can be created via Email. A customer login user can create the cases via his Email. and we wanted to give read access in portal. As when case is created via email we have a functionality to associate the contact to case.
How do we give read permission to community user, as the case owner is salesforce internal user. One thought process is to create account, contact when user is registered( via self registration process or internal user(in such case we would provide read access to the community user on account record via manually or using apex sharing, as the account owner is internal user)) and give case access level controlled by parent.
In this way as the account is created by community user, he will be the owner, and all cases, he will be easily get access without any sharing rules or apex sharing.Is this correct design?.
Any thoughts or knowledge on community users limitations would be appreciated.

Sharing sets should be your course of action

Please [edit] your post to describe the specific type of community user license you are using.

@cropredy I will check all your answers in stackexchange. Thanks.
